# How to add lifetime bounds to the hrtb, and which ones?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I cannot use a concrete type for my struct generic parameter:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a, K: 'a, F>
where
    for<'r> F: Fn(&'r T) -> K,
{
    t: &'a T,
    k: K,
    f: F,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T, &'a T, for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'r T> {
    //
}
```

I think I must add more information the the hrtb generic function, but I cannot figure out what:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:17
   |
10 | impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T, &'a T, for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'r T> {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'r T as FnOnce<(&T,)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'r T as FnOnce<(&'r T,)>>::Output`
note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src/lib.rs:10:6
   |
10 | impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T, &'a T, for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'r T> {
   |      ^^
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/lib.rs:3:29
   |
3  |     for<'r> F: Fn(&'r T) -> K,
   |                             ^
```

What is frustrating is that if my function returns a reference, it works correctly:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a, K: 'a, F>
where
    for<'r> F: Fn(&'r T) -> &'r K,
{
    t: &'a T,
    k: K,
    f: F,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T, T, for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'r T> {
    //
}
```

because then the type for K isn't tied to a specific lifetime. I wonder if I can do that somehow when I return `K` instead of `& 'r K`.

Comment: It seems there is no tag [tag:higher-rank-trait-bounds]. Not sure which one to use.

Comment: It needs to return `&'a T`, is it on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In your trait definiton you tell the compiler that `F` returns a `K` which outlives `'a` (`K: 'a` in the generic).
So all you have to do is return something outliving the associated lifetime `'a` from your `impl`:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a, K: 'a, F>
where
    for<'r> F: Fn(&'r T) -> K,
{
    t: &'a T,
    k: K,
    f: F,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T, &'a T, for<'r> fn(&'r T) -> &'a T> {
    //
}
```

But it will probably be hard to generate something of lifetime `'a` when all you get is something of lifetime `'r` which does not have any bounds.

Maybe you don't want HRTBs after all:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a, K: 'a, F>
where
    F: Fn(&'a T) -> K,
{
    t: &'a T,
    k: K,
    f: F,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T, &'a T, fn(&'a T) -> &'a T> {
    //
}
```

Comment: I couldn't put more information, because that would have been verbose too much, but I cannot do that. The comparison function must work for every lifetime possible, otherwise, the code in my iterator cannot compile. The reason is that when I use the function, the struct is borrowed for the `'a` lifetime. You can see the full code here to see the issue: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d9208b16cb9708eb9766e96cc73872ca

Comment: I've updated my question: maybe what I'm looking for is clearer.

Comment: My hunch is that I cannot express such a thing.

Comment: Uhm this is then actually a XY problem, you don't need HRTBs to fullfill your tests see [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a748ad161fe2fc112577e46324e20bc1) nor do you need `unsafe`

Comment: I'm not gonna change my answer since it still holds for the question you asked here though.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I wrongly assumed that this kind of `mem::replace` stuff would displease the borrow checker (BTW, `mem::take` works here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac32668fb32484d73173289f051c5037). I should have try in that direction. Also, now that you put the 2 functions in one, it feels so obvious. I'm dumb sometimes…

Comment: Not sure what I should do about the Q/A. It doesn't really fit the stackoverflow format…